# Internet explorer is generating an extra element. Suggest me how to get rid of it

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Please use IE for this. Im using IE 9.

Just a side project http://www.somesite.lt

You can find almost at the bottom of the site an element `.gallerywrapper`

For some reason IE is generating two of them. Please, help me find the problem as I am sitting with this almost for three hours for know. Thanks.

Comment: You should provide an example of the code, not a link to a site.

Comment: It's not internet explorer. It's going to be whatever jQuery plugin you're using for the image gallery doing something weird.

Comment: Its not about this error. This error is in all browsers, but only IE is generating an extra element.

Comment: Widor, I really do not know what to provide when there is everything ok in other browsers, but IE is producing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an error in your file

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'livequery' 
wp-e-commerce.js?ver=3.8.6.1.438283, **line 273 character** 2
```

that stopping your script.

Comment: Its not about this error. This error is in all browsers, but only IE is generating an extra element.

Comment: I found out myself. It was the problem with <a name="someelement"></a>  Apparently I didnt close these with </a> Other browsers didnt generate the problem except for IE